# How to access variable or uicontrol created in method with swift?

Tags: ios, variables, methods, swift, controls

I'm building an app with swift, so i have a question here:

When i created a variable or uicontrol in one method , how can i access to it in another method?

ps: Because of logic code, i don't want to create variable , uicontrol outside of method

```
class abc
{
    func method1()
    {
      var img = UIImageView();
      var xyz = 1;
    }
    func method2()
    {
      // access to img control here
      // access to variable xyz here
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to share the created variable to the other method somehow. This can either be through an instance variable, a global of some sort, or you can return it from the method in some fashion.

Comment: how can i do that with swift? that is my question. PHP have global keyword to set global variable but i didn't see that in swift

Answer (score 0):

Use a tuple:

```
   class abc
    {
        func method1()->(UIImageView, Int)
        {
          var img = UIImageView();
          var xyz = 1;
        }
        func method2()
        {
          let (imgControl, xyz) = method1()
          // access to img control here
          // access to variable xyz here
        }
    }
```

Comment: With this way, i have to return value. How it can be work if i define control in func like this:
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)->(UIImageView,testvar:Int) {